# Emotion Api Android linkage with Azure

Tags: android, azure

How to Link the Microsoft's Cognitive Services 'Emotion API' in android with your android app using Azure?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/emotion-api/documentation)?

Comment: yes and didn't find much help there regarding android

Comment: What do you mean by "connect it with your azure account" ?

Comment: i meant how to attach the cognitive services in your own android app using azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to know how to use Azure Emotion API on Android App. There is [a offical document website for Azure Cognitive Services](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/documentation) which include [Emotion API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Emotion-api/documentation), you can follow two `How-to Topics` below to know the basic concepts & usage.

1. [How to Call Emotion API for Video](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Emotion-api/documentation/emotion-api-how-to-topics/HowtoCallEmotionForVideo)
2. [How to Analyze Videos in Real-time](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Emotion-api/documentation/emotion-api-how-to-topics/HowtoAnazlyzeVideo_Emotion)

First of all, you need an Azure subscription to create an Emotion API service like below on Azure portal.

[image]

Then, you can copy the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` on Azure portal as below, and try to use the key to test the Emotion API via [its API reference page](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/563b31ea778daf121cc3a5fa).

[image]

Finally, you can follow the toturial [Emotion API Java for Android Quick Start](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Emotion-api/documentation/QuickStarts/Java) to try to use Emotion API on your Android App.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.